# Compiling QGIS 2.0.1 on Centos (SIP problems)

Tags: qgis, sip, compile

Trying to compile QGIS 2.0.1 on CentOS 6.4 (64 bit):

```
/usr/share/sip/PyQt4/QtGui/qsyntaxhighlighter.sip: In function ‘PyObject* meth_QgsExpressionHighlighter_setCurrentBlockUserData(PyObject*, PyObject*, PyObject*)’:
/usr/share/sip/PyQt4/QtGui/qsyntaxhighlighter.sip:78: error: ‘qtgui_wrap_ancestors’ was not declared in this scope
make[2]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_gui.dir/gui/sipguipart3.cpp.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [python/CMakeFiles/python_module_qgis_gui.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

This is with SIP 4.15.2, Python 2.6.6, and  PyQt-x11-gpl-4.10.3

Any help please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a known issue with latest sip (4.15.x). You should be able to compile using **PyQt4 4.10.2** and **sip 4.14.7**.

Consider [adding a bug report](http://hub.qgis.org/wiki/quantum-gis/Bugreports). A [related issue is #8601](http://hub.qgis.org/issues/8601).